# Laravel API didn't return the desired output

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-10, laravel-api

```
Route::group(\['namespace' =\> 'API\\V1'\], function () {

Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
    Route::get('registration', [CustomerAuthController::class, 'registration']);
});

});
```

I've created this in api.php

And below is the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\V1\\Auth;

use App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller;
use Dotenv\\Validator;
use Illuminate\\Http\\Request;

class CustomerAuthController extends Controller
{

public function registration(Request $request)
{

    $validator = $request->validate(
        [
            'f_name' => 'required',
        ],

    );
    if ($validator) {
        return ["status" => "passed without error"];
    } else {
        return $validator['error'];
    }
}

}
```

It returns the default welcome page for laravel 10... Why???

I've tried

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/registration

on postman but instead of returning in if-else statement, it returns the welcome page...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know, because we can't know your full codes, environments, etc..
Check your defined routes via `php artisan route:list` first.
With your route definition after removing bunch of backslashes, I could get `/api/auth/registration` route correctly.

Comment: This is the main code which I shared with you... rest of the code is the default one when install the new laravel 10 project...